# Roll up / shade floating windows in awesome?

Tags: linux, awesome-wm, window-management

I am trying out awesome at the moment coming from KDE/MATE since many years and I really like it a lot. There's really only one thing that I'm missing from my previous workflows.

Occasionally I'm working with applications that have a lot of floating windows. What I found tremendously helpful in floating WMs was the ability to roll up or shade a window, basically only keeping the titlebar of the application but hiding its window contents.

Is this possible in awesome? Alternatively are there other options like tabbing windows (like in i3) or do you have other suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible in awesome?

Theoretically yes, but practically I do not know about anyone who implemented the necessary magic yet to make this work properly. A semi-good first approximation might be to resize the window to height 1.

Untested sketch:

```
function toggle_roll_up_or_shade(c)
    if c.shade then
        c:geometry{ height = c.shade }
        c.shade = nil
        c.size_hints_honor = c.size_hints_honor_before_shade
    elseif c.floating then
        c.shade = c.height
        c.size_hints_honor_before_shade = c.size_hints_honor
        c.size_hints_honor = false
        c:geometry{ height = 1 }
    end
end
```

The above function would then be bound to some key similar to how Mod+Ctrl+Space is bound to `awful.client.floating.toggle` in the default config.

Here is a variant which might work on AwesomeWM v3.5:

```
function toggle_roll_up_or_shade(c)
    if awful.client.property.get(c, "shade") then
        c:geometry{ height = c.shade }
        awful.client.property.set(c, "shade", nil)
        c.size_hints_honor = c.size_hints_honor_before_shade
    elseif c.floating then
        client.property.set(c, "shade", c.height)
        client.property.set(c, "size_hints_honor_before_shade", c.size_hints_honor)
        c.size_hints_honor = false
        c:geometry{ height = 1 }
    end
end
```

Also, if you want to get the height of the titlebar, you should be able to use `local _, height = c:titlebar_top()`. I'm not sure if this also works in AwesomeWM v3.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick feedback! I played around with your snippet but realized that it basically didn't do anything for me. Upon investigating I noticed that I can only resize the height of windows down to a certain size. A height of 1 as per your example didn't work for me unfortunately. If I change it to something like 50 it does work however. 
`awful.key({ modkey }, "a", function (c) c:geometry{ height = 50 } end)`

I realized I made the rookie mistake of not mentioning that I'm not using an up-to-date version of awesome (v 3.5.1) as I am on CentOS. Could this be a limitation?

Comment: That's what I meant with disabling size hints. Size hints allow clients to say "dear WM, I require at least a size of 50x30". See e.g. https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/documentation/90-FAQ.md.html. I updated the answer to also disable size hints.

Comment: I see, that makes sense to me now :)  The shading is working as expected! I just have to set "height" to the size of my titlebar, rather than 1 to make it work. The last issue I have now is to get the window back into its previous mode. I don't seem to be able to set custom attributes for windows. `c.shade` will always return nil for me. Similar to your example I can get the current windows height by calling `c:geometry().height`, but when I try to set `c.shade = c:geometry().height` it won't set the value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, you wrote that you are on Awesome v3.5.1. Sorry, I missed that part. Only since v4 can one write arbitrary properties to clients. I'll update my answer to use `awful.client.property.set`.

Comment: Thank you SO much! This did the trick! Just had to change all instances of your client calls to `awful.client.property.get/set` and now it's all working as expected. You've been a great help! The time you spent helping me out on this is highly appreciated :)